# Tengo un problema para insertar datos en Sql Server, desde Visual Basic.Net a traves de un Formulario que me inserte los datos en dos tablas

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Esta es la tabla que recibe todos los datos desde btnGuardar en Formulario VB.Net

```
CREATE TABLE TB_InsertarVentas
(
CODEONE NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CATEGORYONE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTSONE NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
IMPORTONE DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
CANTIDONE DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
SUBVALUEONE DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
DATEFECHAONE DATE NOT NULL
)
```

Esta es la tabla que recibe en columna NUEVA_UNIDADES los valores de CANTIDONE desde el Procedimiento Almacenado "SP_InsertarVentasProductos"

```
CREATE TABLE TB_InventProducts
(
@CODE NVARCHAR(50),
@CATEGORY VARCHAR(50),
@PRODUCTS NVARCHAR(200),
@KILOS DECIMAL(10,2),
@NUEVA_UNIDADES DECIMAL(10,2),
@UNIDADES DECIMAL(10,2),
@TOTAL DECIMAL(10,2)
)
```

Procedimiento para Insertar Ventas en Inventario.-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertarVentasProductos]
 @CODE NVARCHAR(50),
    @CATEGORY VARCHAR(50),
    @PRODUCTS NVARCHAR(200),
    @CANTIDONE DECIMAL(10,2)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Verificar si ya existe una fila con las mismas claves en TablaInventProducts
    DECLARE @EXISTE INT;
    SELECT @EXISTE = COUNT(*)
    FROM TB_InventProducts
    WHERE CODE = @CODE AND CATEGORY = @CATEGORY AND PRODUCTS = @PRODUCTS;

    IF @EXISTE > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Actualizar la fila existente
        UPDATE TB_InventProducts
        SET NUEVA_UNIDADES = NUEVA_UNIDADES + @CANTIDONE,
            UNIDADES = UNIDADES + @CANTIDONE,
            TOTAL = TOTAL - @CANTIDONE
        WHERE CODE = @CODE AND CATEGORY = @CATEGORY AND PRODUCTS = @PRODUCTS    
    END
    -- Establecer las columnas en 0.00 después de cada transacción
    UPDATE TB_InventProducts
    SET NUEVA_UNIDADES = 0.00,
        UNIDADES = 0.00
    WHERE CODE = @CODE AND CATEGORY = @CATEGORY AND PRODUCTS = @PRODUCTS;
END
```

Desde este Boton del Formulario se envían los Datos a la tabla TB_InsertarVentas, con el procedimiento para insertar la cantidad en columna NUEVA_UNIDADES de tabla TB_InventProducts.

```
Private Sub btnGuardarVenta_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardarVenta.Click
    Dim FormInsertVentProduct As New FormInsertVentProduct
    Dim DGVVentasProducts As New DataGridView
    Dim DGVImportList As New DataGridView
    Dim RadButtPagoCont As New RadioButton
    Dim RadButtPagoDifer As New RadioButton
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Origen de la DataBase; Initial Catalog=DB_ESTEMATI; Integrated Security=True")
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    Dim DATEFECHAONE As Date = Date.Today
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing
    Try
        ' Iniciar la transacción
        transaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
        For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In Me.DGVVentasProducts.Rows
            If Not fila.IsNewRow Then ' Verificar si no es una fila nueva
                If fila Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox("Ingrese datos")
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    ' Insertar en TablaInsertarVentas
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TB_InsertarVentas VALUES (@CODEONE, @CATEGORYONE, @PRODUCTSONE, @IMPORTONE, @CANTIDONE, @SUBVALUEONE, @DATEFECHAONE)", conn, transaction)

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODEONE", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("CODEONE").Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORYONE", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("CATEGORYONE").Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCTSONE", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("PRODUCTSONE").Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMPORTONE", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("IMPORTONE").Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CANTIDONE", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("CANTIDONE").Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUBVALUEONE", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("SUBVALUEONE").Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEFECHAONE", Convert.ToDateTime(DATEFECHAONE.Date.ToString(fila.Cells("DATEFECHAONE").FormattedValue)))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatementType", "Update")
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    ' Llamar al procedimiento almacenado para actualizar TablaInventProducts
                    Dim cmdActualizarVentasProductos As New SqlCommand("SP_InsertarVentasProductos", conn, transaction)
                    cmdActualizarVentasProductos.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                    ' Utiliza los nombres de parámetros que coincidan con los definidos en el procedimiento almacenado
                    cmdActualizarVentasProductos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("CODEONE").Value))
                    cmdActualizarVentasProductos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("CATEGORYONE").Value))
                    cmdActualizarVentasProductos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUCTS", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("PRODUCTSONE").Value))
                    cmdActualizarVentasProductos.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CANTIDONE", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("CANTIDONE").Value))
                    cmdActualizarVentasProductos.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ' Commit de la transacción si todo se ejecuta correctamente
        transaction.Commit()
        MsgBox("DATA INSERT SUCCESSFULLY")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Rollback de la transacción en caso de error
        If transaction IsNot Nothing Then
            transaction.Rollback()
        End If
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        ' Cerrar la conexión después de completar todas las transacciones
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()

        End If
    End Try
    'transaction = conn.Dispose()
    Me.DGVVentasProducts.Rows.Clear()
    Me.lblTotalVenta.Text = ""

    FormInsertVentProduct.Show() '

    Call Consulta()

End Sub
```

Modifique codigo de Procedimiento en diversas formas, ingresé codigo facilitado por ChatGPT Y tampoco se efectua ia inserción en tabla TB_InventProductos pero si en TB_InsertarVentas. Solicito quien pudiera indicarme donde puede estar el inconveniente, se lo agradeceré.

Comment: No entiendo porque usas un procedimiento almacenado para una cosa, y un insert directo para otra cosa, cuando basicamente estas controlando por codigo lo que hace el SP.. de paso, ese SP no va a funcionar nunca, porque se ejecuta en otro entorno diferente a su insert, y como no hiciste commit, la fila no existe...

Comment: Ahora estoy tratando de resolver otro inconveniente, porque mudé la Base de Datos de Sql Server a DB Browser for SQLite para empaquetar todo, pero me estoy dando con el problema que he creado la base de datos y las tablas pero me sale mensaje de error que no encuentra la tabla y la TablaRegistrarse en la base de datos, hice una consulta de inserccion en Execute SQL y funciona bien, incorporé la base en el archivo de mi aplicacion, copié la ruta para pegarla en App.Config y aún asi sigue el mismo mensaje, desinstalé la Aplicacion de la Base de datos y volví a instalar la aplicacion de base

Comment: pasaron varios meses y me perdi... cerra esta pregunta, y hace tu pregunta acorde a tu nuevo escenario...